# SQL: Count the actions per customer

Tags: sql, sas

I need some SQL help.

My table contains Customer ID, date and the action description. It looks in the following way:

[image: Screenshot]

I want it to have the following structure: each time any actions have been done in the same day by the same customer, then it counts to one single action per customer (maybe also to create a numeric column with "1" inside each cell per customer per distinct date). So, at the end I want to have the following structure:

```
Customer - Date (only distinct dates for each cutomer) - Action (1).
```

Then finally I want to count the sum of actions per customer for a specific timeframe.

Comment: Welcome Maria, you may only ask specific questions. Yours can be debated for days. Read the [ask], show what you did and how it did not work.

Comment: you may try some SQL features like `count(col) from TABLE where <conditions> group by col`

Comment: `select ID_KUNDE, count(*) from ??? group by COD_SE_ACTION where TST_EVENT between (start of timeframe) AND (end of timeframe)`

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results, as tabular text.

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this using group by and count

Updated query:

```
SELECT CA.ID, CA.COD_SE_ACTION, COUNT(CA.COD_SE_ACTION), TST_EVENT FROM 
CUSTOMER_ACTIONS CA GROUP BY CA.ID, CA.COD_SE_ACTION,TST_EVENT ORDER BY 
ID,CA.COD_SE_ACTION ;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but each time an action was performed at the same day (per customer), it should count as one action per day per customer. With this code I only get a sum of the actions per customer per day.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT CustomerId, SUM(Count) FROM ( 
SELECT 
   CA.ID [CustomerId], 
   CA.COD_SE_ACTION [Action], 
   COUNT(CA.COD_SE_ACTION) [Count], 
   TST_EVENT [Date]
FROM CUSTOMER_ACTIONS CA 
GROUP BY 
   CA.ID, 
   CA.COD_SE_ACTION, 
   TST_EVENT 
 ) WHERE Date >= '2020/01/01' AND Date <= '2020/10/10'
GROUP BY CustomerId
```